# Для чего используется точка в .=

Tags: php

В PHP:

```
$pass_phrase .= chr(rand(97, 122));
```

Для чего используется точка?

Comment: Есть строка "Привет мир". Вы сделали что-то вроде `$str .= "Hello!";`. Теперь строка будет равна "Привет мирHello". Оно как бы просто добавляет строку в конец.

Comment: точка это оператор конкатенации  http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php

крч это значит что к переменной $pass_phrase добавить все что после =
например 1 + 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Строковые операторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)

Оператор присваивания с конкатенацией `.=`, который присоединяет правый аргумент к левому:

```
$pass_phrase .= chr(rand(97, 122));
```

Оператор конкатенации `.`, который возвращает строку, представляющую собой соединение левого и правого аргумента:

```
$pass_phrase = $pass_phrase . chr(rand(97, 122));
```