# Вопрос по php зачем нужен оператор конкатенации

Tags: php

Смотрите, есть способ в php, как ты можешь соединить строки следующим способом:

> $a . 'что-то' . $b

Но зачем столько возни, когда можно просто написать в двойных кавычках

> "$a что-то $b"

и выведет то же самое???

p.s. только начал изучать сей великолепный язык

Comment: Когда у вас вместо $a будет например `($a * 2)` будет проблематично написать его внутри строки. А конкатенация отлично справится.

Comment: Или результат вызова функции.

Comment: А как вы запишете в двойных кавычках, к примеру, оператор инкремента? Типа вот так: `"$a что-то ++$b"` ? ... Не всё можно впихнуть внутрь кавычек.

Comment: P.S. в действительно великолепных языках в строку можно вписать вообще любое выражение. Но php к ним не относится (imho) :)

Comment: чтобы распарсить строку и вычленить оттуда `$` с переменными, кстати, тоже надо время. хотя в случае константной строки с подстановкой переменных скорее всего байткод будет содержать упрощенную конструкцию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Для чего используется точка в .=](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843172/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2/843175#843175)

Comment: $a . 'что-то' . $b - менее ресурсоемкий, есть еще вариант echo $a, 'что-то',$b;

Comment: А есть еще echo "{$a} что-то {$b}"))

Answer (score 3):

При написании

```
$a . 'что-то' . $b
```

`'что-то'` скешируется на этапе компиляции скрипта и не будет требовать дополнительных ресурсов и памяти на разбор строки и поиск в ней переменных.

Описание процесса с [Хабра](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/318008/)

Encapsed-строки — это значения, в которых выполняется внутреннее сканирование на наличие переменных. Они объявляются с помощью двойных кавычек, или Heredoc-синтаксиса. Алгоритм анализирует значение и отделяет переменные от строк. Например:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$c = "Мне нравится $a и $b";
```

При анализе строки $c движок должен получить строку: «Мне нравится foo и bar».

Вот что делает PHP 5:

- Выделяет буфер для «Мне нравится»;
- Выделяет буфер для «Мне нравится foo»;
- Добавляет (копирует в памяти) в последний буфер «Мне нравится» и “foo”, возвращает его временное содержимое;
- Выделяет новый буфер для «Мне нравится foo и»;
- Добавляет (копирует в памяти) « Мне нравится foo» и «и» в этот последний буфер и возвращает его временное содержимое;
- Выделяет новый буфер для «Мне нравится foo и bar»;
- Добавляет (копирует в памяти) «Мне нравится foo и» и “bar” в этот последний буфер и возвращает его содержимое;
- Освобождает все промежуточные использованные буферы;
- Возвращает значение последнего буфера.

Много работы, верно? Такой алгоритм в PHP 5 аналогичен тому, что используется при работе со строками в С. Но дело в том, что он плохо масштабируется. Этот алгоритм не оптимален при работе с очень длинными encapsed-строками, включающими в себя большое количество переменных. А ведь encapsed-строки часто используются в PHP.

В PHP 7 всё работает иначе:

- Создаётся стек;
- В него помещаются все элементы, которые нужно добавить;
- Когда алгоритм доходит до конца encapsed-строки, единовременно выделяется память необходимого размера, в которую перемещаются все части данных, в нужные места.

Телодвижения с памятью остались, однако никакие промежуточные буферы, как в PHP 5, уже не используются. В PHP 7 лишь один раз выделяется память для финальной строки, вне зависимости от количества частей строки и переменных.

Comment: То есть, если используешь PHP 7, то отличий в производительности практически не будет?

Comment: в 7 будет немного оптимальней, но все равно будут накладные расходы